# Show recent posts in menu?

Tags: categories, menus

I'm building a menu which contains categories. 
Is  there a way to make each menu option show a list of recent posts in that category when you hover over it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a walker like this,

```
class Walker_Recent_Post_Category extends Walker_Category {
    function start_el(&$output, $category, $depth, $args) { 
         extract($args); 

         $cat_name = esc_attr( $category->name); 
         $cat_name = apply_filters( 'list_cats', $cat_name, $category ); 

         $list_recent_cat_post = '<ul class="show-hide">';
         $args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'category_name' => $category->name );
         $myposts = get_posts( $args );
         foreach( $myposts as $mypost ) :  
            $list_recent_cat_post .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($mypost->ID) . '">' . $mypost->post_title . '</a></li>';
         endforeach; 
         $list_recent_cat_post .= '</ul>';



         $link = '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" '; 
         if ( $use_desc_for_title == 0 || empty($category->description) ) 
             $link .= 'title="' . sprintf(__( 'View all posts filed under %s' ), $cat_name) . '"'; 
         else 
             $link .= 'title="' . esc_attr( strip_tags( apply_filters( 'category_description', $category->description, $category ) ) ) . '"'; 
         $link .= '>'; 
         $link .= $cat_name . '</a>'; 

         if ( (! empty($feed_image)) || (! empty($feed)) ) { 
             $link .= ' '; 

             if ( empty($feed_image) ) 
                 $link .= '('; 

             $link .= '<a href="' . get_category_feed_link($category->term_id, $feed_type) . '"'; 

             if ( empty($feed) ) 
                 $alt = ' alt="' . sprintf(__( 'Feed for all posts filed under %s' ), $cat_name ) . '"'; 
             else { 
                 $title = ' title="' . $feed . '"'; 
                 $alt = ' alt="' . $feed . '"'; 
                 $name = $feed; 
                 $link .= $title; 
             } 

             $link .= '>'; 

             if ( empty($feed_image) ) 
                 $link .= $name; 
             else 
                 $link .= "<img src='$feed_image'$alt$title" . ' />'; 
             $link .= '</a>'; 
             if ( empty($feed_image) ) 
                 $link .= ')'; 
         } 

         if ( isset($show_count) && $show_count ) 
             $link .= ' (' . intval($category->count) . ')'; 

         if ( isset($show_date) && $show_date ) { 
             $link .= ' ' . gmdate('Y-m-d', $category->last_update_timestamp); 
         } 


         $link .= $list_recent_cat_post;


         if ( isset($current_category) && $current_category ) 
             $_current_category = get_category( $current_category ); 

         if ( 'list' == $args['style'] ) { 
             $output .= "\t<li"; 
            $class = 'cat-item cat-item-'.$category->term_id; 
             if ( isset($current_category) && $current_category && ($category->term_id == $current_category) ) 
                 $class .=  ' current-cat'; 
             elseif ( isset($_current_category) && $_current_category && ($category->term_id == $_current_category->parent) ) 
                 $class .=  ' current-cat-parent'; 
             $output .=  ' class="'.$class.'"'; 
             $output .= ">$link\n"; 
         } else { 
             $output .= "\t$link\n"; 
         } 
    }   
}
```

then call the walker like this,

```
    <ul>
       <?php wp_list_categories(
                array(
                    'show_count'=>1,
                    'title_li'  =>'',
                    'walker'    => new Walker_Recent_Post_Category()
                )
             ); ?>
    </ul>
```

it will display something like this,

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/category/my-category/" title="View all posts filed under my category">my category</a> (1)
        <ul class="show-hide">
            <li><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/2011/06/twetwetewrwe/">twetwetewrwe</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/category/uncategorized/" title="View all posts filed under Uncategorized">Uncategorized</a> (7)
        <ul class="show-hide">
            <li><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/2011/06/5th/">5th</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/2011/06/twtwe/">twtwe</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/2010/08/five-ways-widget-manufacturing-can-be-bungled/">Lorem Ipsum dolor sin amet</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/2010/08/help-me/">help-me!</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/2010/08/hello-world-2/">Hello world!</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and some jQuery touches on the html : [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/Yfbbx/)

Comment: Nice approach.  :)

Comment: That looks really really good. Gonna try that out. Thank you for your comprehensive answer!

Comment: This solution works with wp_list_categories; Is there any chance of getting this to work with wp_nav_menu?

Comment: you could post it as another separate question ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you make your navigation region widgetized then it is possible. For example make your horizontal nav area widgetized and then drop 'recent post' widget in that area. I have yet to try this so posting this answer as suggestion. By the way you have to work on that widgetized area as well in terms of design for making it to work.